# How do I find closest element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<td>
  <input type="text" size="40" value="" name="related_image" id="related_image">  
  <input type="button" class="button addImage" value="Get image url">
</td>
<td>
  <input type="text" size="40" value="" name="alternative_image" id="alternative_image">  
  <input type="button" class="button addImage" value="Get image url">
</td>
```

I need to figure out which button I click, then add some text to the nearest input text field.
E.g. if I click the button in the first `<td>`, then I need to input some text into `related_image` text field.

I've tried with the followin jQuery, but it's not working:

```
jQuery('.addImage').click(function() {
  var tmp = jQuery(this).closest("input[type=text]").attr('name');
  alert(tmp);
});
```

(I'm just retrieving the inputs name for testing.)

I think I might have to use `find` and / or `siblings`. But I'm not quite sure how.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**

I just managed to use this code
`addImageEvent = jQuery(this).prevAll("input[type=text]:first")`

Is using `prevAll` a bad choice?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try:

```
var tmp = $(this).siblings(":text").attr("name");
```

The `closest()` method you're using finds the closest ancestor, which is not what you want here.

Comment: aaaah - somehow I though that siblings = children. But siblings = brother / sister. Thanks. I see there are multiple solutions to this "problem".

Comment: if there are many siblings exists, then how to find nearest one ?

Comment: it works like a charm, thanks :) i tried "next" and "closest" before siblings! :D

Answer (score 5):

[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) finds a parent, in this case you need [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), like this:

```
jQuery('.addImage').click(function() {
  var tmp = jQuery(this).siblings("input[type=text]").attr('name');
  alert(tmp);
});
```

Or if the format is always consistent like your example, just use [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), like this:

```
jQuery('.addImage').click(function() {
  var tmp = jQuery(this).prev().attr('name');
  alert(tmp);
});
```

Comment: Yup. As I commented above - I mixed parent / child, thinking siblings = children. Thansk for the solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a 'closest' implementation that aims at descendants instead of parents:

```
$.fn.nearest = function(selector) {
    var nearest, node = this, distance = 10000;
    node.find(selector).each(function(){
        var n = $(this),
            d = n.parentsUntil(node).size();
        if (d < distance) {
            distance = d;
            nearest = n;
        } else if (d == distance) {
            nearest.add(this);
        }
    });
    return nearest;
};
```