# Jquery slide down closest div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When `<li>`is pressed it should slide down closest div with clas `.notification_pop_up`  .
Could someone give me advice? I think i need to use one of these `next()` or `find()` but i have no idea how. Thank u.
**HTML**

```
<li class="pr_news"><div class="notification_pop_up"></div></li> 
<li class="pr_messages"><div class="notification_pop_up"></div></li>
```

Comment: what is your definition of closest, like walking up the tree, siblings, or children/child nodes.

Comment: `next` is used for sibling while `find` is for childrens, It seems that you need both next and find.

Comment: Sorry, i will edit my question, i wrote it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('li').on('click',function(){
    $('.notification_pop_up',this)
      .slideDown();
});
```

or

```
$('li').on('click',function(){
    $('.notification_pop_up:first',this)
      .slideDown();
});
```

or

```
$('li').on('click',function(){
    $(this).find('.notification_pop_up:first')
      .slideDown();
});
```

or

```
$('li').on('click',function(){
    $(this).find('.notification_pop_up')
      .first()
      .slideDown();
});
```

But by far the most efficient is the following:

```
$(document).on('click','li:has(.notification_pop_up)',function(){
    $('.notification_pop_up',this)
      .slideDown();
});
```

Comment: Technically, this will slide down all the notification_pop_ups within the li, but your example code only showed one.  You can use .first() or :first to grab just the first.

Comment: All of these will work with you examples.  The first one will open all the notification_pop_up, while the next 3 are essentially equivalent.  The last one uses a global click handler on document instead of binding a click handler on each element.  This is also very useful for pages that might modify the dom after the page is loaded (ajax, or template engine like angular, x-tmpl, or knockout) .

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').click(function() { $(this).find('div.notification_pop_up').eq(0).slideDown(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li").click(function(){
   $(this).find(".notification_pop_up:frist").slideDown();
});
```

I like putting `:first` in the query instead of `.first()`, so it returns a set of size one, instead of doing the entire set and then getting the first value

Comment: Can u check my question now , i made some changes.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with answer. I used this code and it works perfect. Thank u guys anyway.

```
$(li).click(function(){
    $(this).find(".notification_pop_up").fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like following please check it out.

```
$('li').on('click',function(){
    $(this).siblings('.notification_pop_up').slideDown();
});
```

you can also check on following link.

[How do I find closest element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623103/how-do-i-find-closest-element-with-jquery)