# How can I get the closest input value next to a img jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the closest input value when user click the img in jquery, how can I do that? For instance, if user click img a, it will get the value'1'.

```html
<img src="">a</img>
<input type="hidden" value="1" />
<img src="">b</img>
<input type="hidden" value="2" />
<img src="">c</img>
<input type="hidden" value="3" />
<img src="">d</img>
<input type="hidden" value="4" />
<img src="">e</img>
```

Comment: Use `next()`, `$(this).next().val()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623103/how-do-i-find-closest-element-with-jquery

Comment: closest or next? what about the last img tag? there is no next input for that. in that case you need to get the previous input value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)**

```js
$('img').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).next().val();
  alert(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" alt=a />
<input type="hidden" value="1" />
<img src="" alt=b />
<input type="hidden" value="2" />
<img src="" alt=c />
<input type="hidden" class=a value="3" />
<img src="" alt=d />
<input type="hidden" value="4" />
<img src="" alt=e />
```

**Update:** If there is any other elements after the input then you need to use **[`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextall/)** and **[`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/)**

```js
$('img').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).nextAll('input').first().val();
  // you can avoid first(), since val() return value of first element from selector
  // var value = $(this).nextAll('input').val();
  alert(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" alt=a />
<input type="hidden" value="1" />
<span>hello</span>
<img src="" alt=b />
<input type="hidden" value="2" />
<span>hello</span>
<img src="" alt=c />
<input type="hidden" value="3" />
<span>hello</span>
<img src="" alt=d />
<input type="hidden" value="4" />
<img src="" alt=e />
```

Comment: And `.val()`, also no need of `'input'` to the `next`

Comment: Not `value`, `input.val()` or if you want to use `value` then use `var input = $(this).next('input')[0];`

Comment: @Tushar : we can use `input` selector , there is no restriction. `Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.`

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it gave me 'undefined', is that because I have a couple tag between the img and the input? I edit the code a little bit.

Comment: @conan : in that case use `var value = $(this).nextAll('input').first().val();`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Yes, but that is not required at all as `next` selects the `immediate next element` no matter if you pass the selector or not see the demo fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/mzz68Lcr/

Comment: @Tushar : Your jsfiddle works only if the input next to img, but my situation is that the div between the img and input, your jsfiddle code won't work if I  put the div between the img and the input. Thanks

Comment: @Pranav C Bala, I change your code a little bit. I put a span between the input and img, then your code won't work, that is my situation.Thanks

Comment: @conan `$('img').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).nextAll('input').first().val();
  alert(value);
});`

Comment: it still give me undefined. I think if there is a span tag between input and img, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('img').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).next().val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img").click(function(){
   alert($(this).parents('.input-group').find('input').val());
});
```

Hope this will help you !!

Answer (score 0):

There will be img tags other than these in your page, I guess. in that case it will be better if you can surround these img tags with a div and do something like below.

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <img src="">a</img>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" />
    <img src="">b</img>
    <input type="hidden" value="2" />
    <img src="">c</img>
    <input type="hidden" value="3" />
    <img src="">d</img>
    <input type="hidden" value="4" />
    <img src="">e</img>
</div>
```

and the jquery you should put is,

```
$("#parentDiv img").each(function(){

    $(this).click(function(){

        if($(this).next().val()){

            alert($(this).next().val());
        }
    });
});
```

if your page doesn't have any other img tags other than these just keep the html as it is and put this peace of code

```
$("img").click(function(){

    if($(this).next().val()){

        alert($(this).next().val());
    }
});
```